# File upload PHP script not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues getting a file upload script to work. The strange thing is that it works fine for an image field I have setup, but not for the form field intended for .mp3 or similar files, and I am using the same script for each. Here is my code:

```
$download = $_FILES['download']['name'];
$downloadtarget = "events/" . $name . "/";

if(move_uploaded_file($download, $downloadtarget)) {
echo 'do stuff';
}else{
echo 'don't do stuff';
```

I always seem to get the latter "dont do stuff" with the file upload. 
The same script except interchanging:

```
$download = $_FILES['download']['name'];
```

with

```
$download = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
```

earlier in the script works fine, the file uploads without issue.

Comment: what is the size of mp3 file?

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>  Posting form this type

Comment: I think it should be `$download = $_FILES['download']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Sidenote: This `echo 'don't do stuff';` will surely throw a parse error. Change to either `echo 'don\'t do stuff';` or `echo "don't do stuff";`

Comment: what is print_r($_FILES) output

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `$_FILES['download']['tmp_name'];`
 try

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["download"]["tmp_name"],
          "events/" . $_FILES["download"]["name"]);
```

also form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property

for more info about file upload follow link :- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: tried this, same issues persist. also, file size of mp3 thus far has never been in excess of 5mb, however my host places no limits on this, and there are no statements in my script that limit file size, or even type. also, the form certainly does have entype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: so have you any error? also check your upload dir is writable

Comment: @RakeshSharma some good programmers says http://www.w3fools.com/. So avoid using it. :)

Comment: @RakeshSharma, please avoid w3schools for reference too many errors and misleading info there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $download = $_FILES['download']['name'];
    $downloadtarget = "events/" . $download . "";
    $temp_name = $_FILES['download']['tmp_name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $downloadtarget)) {
        echo 'do stuff';
    } else {
        echo 'don\'t do stuff';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this

```
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 4)
            {
                $file_attachement_message="No Files attached";
            }
            else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){

                $attachement_

error=$_FILES["file"]["error"];
            $file_attachement_message="File attachement failed with error code:$attachement_error";
        }
        else
        {

            if(!is_dir('../attachements'))
            {
                mkdir('../attachements');
            }
            if (file_exists("../attachements/".$id))
            {
                // echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists";
                $file_attachement_message="Attached file already exists in db";
            }
            else
            {
                $info=pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
                $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
                $newname="$risk_id.".$ext;
               ["tmp_name"],"../attachements/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../attachements/".$newname);

                $file_attachement_message="and File Attached successfully";
            }
        }
```

Comment: please check the syntax errors before posting answer there are too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears to have been file size. Tested with picture vs an mp3, works without issue. Further reading shows php.ini defaults to 2mb limit.